# How to escape double and single quotes in java -jar bash command for Spring Boot Application containing Property with double quotes and single quotes

Tags: java, spring, bash, spring-boot, azure

I have come across a very **strange situation** while deploying a `Java jar` using `Azure DevOps Pipelines`

I am using `task: Bash@3` to execute a `shell` command `'java -jar my-app.jar'`

I have 1 `secret` called `db-password` from `Azure KeyVault` as a `variable` whose value is say `123"xk'cv`

I need to set this as a `Spring Boot Application property` in order to access the `datasource` in my **application**.

The `yml` script to run java -jar command is as follows:

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Deploy jar'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        cd build/libs
        java -jar -Dspring.datasource.password=$(db-password) my-app.jar
```

Due to the presence of one **double quote** `"` or **single quote** `'` in the `secret` value, the `Azure Devops pipeline` is **failing** with the following error:

```
/myagent/_work/_temp/xxxx.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/myagent/_work/_temp/xxxx.sh: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

**I need a way to:**

Escape the double quote or single quote from the `secret` value and execute the above pipeline.

Changing the secret value is not an option as it is a production database and multiple teams are accessing it.

The Question might not be related to Azure Pipeline, it may be a simple bash or Spring boot hack.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd start by trying out surrounding the value with *single* quotes

Comment: With this message : `unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''`, it seems a single qutoe is causing problem.

Comment: Remove all four single quotes?

Comment: @Philippe I have updated the question, in the password there is a single quote as well, I thought the message is for double quotes.

Comment: @g00se I tried with `java -jar -Dspring.datasource.password='$(db-password)' my-app.jar ` but got same error. Looks like it is the **single quote** causing issue, like @Philippe mentioned.

Comment: @Cyrus not sure what you mean by remove all four single quotes

Comment: *whose value is say 123"xk'cv* Oh hang on - so you've got more than one type of quote in there?

Comment: @g00se unfortunately yes, its a mix of symbols, letters and digits, I wouldn't be able to remember it even If I tried :Dx

Comment: At the moment, you seem to be returning the password from a function or a script..?

Comment: @g00se Yes, from an azure key vault. like so `$(db-password)`. on the other hand I tried the same command in a shell script editor, I am getting syntax error, I am not able to eliminate both single and double quotes even after using a combination of quotes :D

Comment: Not sure what's happening. Just tested with `java -Dbadpass=$(cat badpass) PassView` which just echoes that property to stdout. A nasty 'password' with single and double quotes in it. It was fine

Answer (score 1):

I put this as an answer for formatting purposes, try this :

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Deploy jar'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        cd build/libs
        java -jar -Dspring.datasource.password="$(cat << 'END_OF_STRING'
        $(db-password)
        END_OF_STRING
        )" my-app.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's docs on [using secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash), "You'll need to map secret variable as environment variables to reference them in YAML pipelines."

I'm not entirely clear on Azure's YAML structure, but AIUI that'll mean adding something like this at *some* level under `steps`:

```
env:
  password: $(db-password)
```

And using it like this in the bash script:

```
script: |
  cd build/libs
  java -jar -Dspring.datasource.password="$password" my-app.jar
```

This way the password isn't actually substituted into the script's text; instead, bash will see `"$password"` and expand it to the environment variable's value. Since it's in double-quotes, bash doesn't do any parsing *at all* on the variable's value, so any quotes, spaces, wildcards, etc will not cause parsing problems.

BTW, many sources recommend using all-caps variable names for environment variables, but lower- and mixed-case names are actually safer because of all of the all-caps names that have special meanings. If you don't want any of those special meanings, use lowercase to avoid accidental conflicts with any of those special-meaning variables.